# SharedPrefenrences not storing boolean value

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

Am trying save boolean FAVOURITE data in sharedPreferences. when phone is rotated or closed .It is not working it is taking default value. I don't know whats wrong with this code. i am unable to figure out whats the problem is can someone show me the problem with the code

```
//Context context =this;

 String FAVOURITE = "selected";

boolean favourite = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        favourite = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(FAVOURITE,false);
        Toast.makeText(this,""+favourite,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    final Bundle queryBundle = new Bundle();

    movieObject=(CardsClass)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("movieObject");

    setTitle(movieObject.getmTitle());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    final ImageView fav = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fav);

    fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (favourite == false) {

                favourite = true;

                fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_on);

                Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, favourite + " is added to favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                queryBundle.putBoolean(FAVOURITE,favourite);

            }

            else if(favourite){

                favourite=false;

                fav.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_off);

                queryBundle.putBoolean(FAVOURITE,favourite);

                Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, movieObject.getmTitle() + " is removed from favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: where is your code of storing it in the `SharedPreferences` ?

Comment: I tried to use Bundle. i replaced it. now it is working

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're doing the wrong thing. You should do something like:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean(FAVOURITE, favorite); // then you can check the favorite value in onCreate as well.
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.favorite = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(FAVOURITE);
    // do something here when restore.
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To write or read in the [**`SharedPreferences`**](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Write:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean(FAVORITE, favorite);
editor.commit();
```

Read:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean favorite = sharedPref.getBoolean(FAVORITE, true);
```